# Debug which Javascript runs with an element is clicked on

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug

Consider an element `<img id='hitMe' />` which is referenced in a jQuery function with either `$('#hitme').click()` or possibly `$(document).on('click', '#hitme')`. How can I find these functions in the Javascript source code, other than grepping for the string `hitme`? Consider that grepping is not feasible as the string may have an arbitrarily large amount of references, and there may be a very large number of imported Javascript files.

Perhaps there might be a way to have Firebug step into Javascript functions that are run, after page load, on a line-by-line basis? Consider that I don't know where to set a breakpoint because I don't know which function is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that catches the moment in which the event is trigger (dispatched) rather than the moment in which the listener is being added (on/click).

It can be done by overriding `jQuery.event.dispatch`.
for example:

```
(function($){
    var old = $.event.dispatch;
    $.event.dispatch = function(event){
        if(event.type=='click'){
            var handlers = ( $._data( this, "events" ) || {} )[ event.type ] || [];
            console.log('handlers', handlers[0]);
        }
        old.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

In this example I chose to print the content of the function to the console, but it could also be useful to debug it like  [Omri Sivan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1263595/omri-sivan) suggested, with `debugger;`. With Chrome you should be able to right click on the function to "Show function definition".

Answer (score 1):

Chrome or Chromium can help you there. Make a right click on the element you want to explore, chose "Inspect element", have a look into the right panel which starts with "Computed Style", "Style"... and at the bottom of it you will find the section "Event Listeners", which gives you information about what events are listened and where in the code it was appended.

Comment: Thank you. I notice that it only mentions that, for instance, Jquery may be listening for the 'click' event. How might I know where exists the code that uses Jquery to listen on the element?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Visual Event bookmarklet. What follows, is a shameless copy-paste from the site:

Visual Event is an open source Javascript bookmarklet which provides debugging information about events that have been attached to DOM elements. 
Visual Event shows:

- Which elements have events attached to them
- The type of events attached to an element
- The code that will be run with the event is triggered
- The source file and line number for where the attached function was defined (Webkit browsers and Opera only)

http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2

Comment: This is a nice bookmark, but it only shows which lines of the jQuery library are bound to the element. If it would show the code which uses jQuery then it would be a killer app.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (I'm using Chrome/Chrome Dev Tools):

1. Override jQuery's on/click function with something like:

   `var old = $.fn.on; 
   $.fn.on = function() { console.log('called on'); debugger; old.apply(this, arguments);}`
2. Every call to .on() should now pass through you (synchronously) and pause at the 'debugger;' statement.
3. Once paused, look under 'Call Stack' and locate the function you are looking for (e.g. the function that invoked .on()). You can also add some condition to the overriding function above to make sure not every call to .on() pauses.

[image: Chrome Dev Tools - script paused]

Answer (score 0):

In chromium based browsers exists this funcition: monitorEvents

Comment: This looks like the beginning of a good answer. Go on.